# A better method for counting documents with object ID's using Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Currently I'm querying MongoDB with Mongoose to search for a particular category with a specific ObjectID (e.g. 5ca510c87cf5db0017a59d5d) and then count the documents in a Process with that particular category. However, I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this that can query the `name`  field (e.g. 'Primary') of category instead, that way it can work across any other database without modifying the code to a specific ID.

This is a Node.js application with Express being used for MVC and Mongoose for ODM.

I've referred to Mongoose's `populate` function in the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), but can't seem to find a good analogy.

Category Model:

```
var CategorySchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true, min: 3, max: 100}
});
```

Process Model:

```
var ProcessSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    machine: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Machine', required: true},
    summary: {type: String, required: true},
    serial_number: {type: String, required: true},
    category: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category'}]
  }
);
```

Process Controller:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {

    async.parallel({
        ...
        process_category_primary_count: function(callback) {
            Process.countDocuments({category: '5ca510c87cf5db0017a59d5d'},callback);
        },
        process_category_intermediate_count: function(callback) {
            Process.countDocuments({category: '5ca510f57cf5db0017a59d5e'},callback);
        },
        process_category_finishing_count: function(callback) {
            Process.countDocuments({category: '5ca511017cf5db0017a59d5f'},callback);
        },
        ...
    }, function(err, results) {
        res.render('index', { title: 'Dashboard Home',
                              error: err,
                              data: results });
    });
};
```

By default a `find` all query for process will produce a result like this:

```
{ category: [ 5c9d48508ee1353a2786c7d0 ],
    _id: 5ca3ca9a9743b52602d88c57,
    name: 'Milling-Detailing',
    machine: 5c9e407c6e0b26209b55dbbd,
    summary: 'Detailing pass for each object.',
    serial_number: '1002',
    __v: 0 }
```

So in essence: I'd like to use a Category 'name' rather than an 'id' to search and count the Process collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would have to use `$lookup` to be able to do this, so it would be a fair bit more code.
According to the MongoDB docs, `.countDocuments()` also does an aggregation and adds `{ $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }` as the last stage of the pipeline after it matches on the query you pass in. This is just replicating the same process.
It would return a one item cursor `[{ _id: null, count: <someCount> }]` (-:
The `$unwind` is to turn the `category` field from an array into a single record.

```js
Process.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'categories',
      localField: 'category',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'category'
    }
  },
  { $unwind: '$category' },
  { $match: { 'category.name': 'categoryName' } },
  { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
], callback)
```

Comment: Yes, that works! Added as answered. Very powerful, this aggregate and look up is. The result is in the form [ { _id: null, count: 3 } ]. Would there be a better way to get an exact number ('3') rather than slice the result (e.g. result[0].count)?

Comment: You would have to use a helper function for that. `aggregate` returns a cursor which will always be in the form of an array.

Comment: OK, I tried that out. Think I have a working chain now. Many thanks!